# How to build a Polymer project for different environments

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

In my Polymer app, I have a connection to firebase and also support Google signin. However, for my dev and staging environments, I would have a different firebase endpoints and google client ids.

My question is, how do i build my Polymer app for these different environments without manually updating the firebase endpoints or google client ids etc?

In languages like C++, we have preprocessor directives like #ifdef which can be used to conditionally compile for the desired environments. Though not a Polymer specific issue, but has this problem already been solved by Polymer perhaps via one of their projects like starter kit?

Thanks.